# Are minitoc and tableof packages compatible?

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, minitoc

**Edit:** Okay, I worked longer on my issue. I isolated the issue and produced a very minimal code to reproduce the issue.

The following code does not produce what I wish.

- Each chapter should contain a `minitoc` at the beginning.
- Each section should start by tags which are linked to other section through `hyperref` and should end by a table of section containing a main tag of the section. For instance, if the `sec1` define the tag 'a', then all sections referring to the tag 'a' should appear in this last table.

I produced a latex document able to do this. However, `\tableof` and `\minitoc` does not work long after the first call.

So there is an example what I want on the left, and what I have on the right :
[image: On the left, what I want. On the right, what I have]

And here is the new code :

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tableof}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\newcommand{\sectionHead}[3]{
    %1 : title
    %2 : tags reference
    %3 : tags

    %tag the content
    \toftagthis{#3}
    \section[#1]{ \hypertarget{#2}{#1} }
    %for visual content
    \keywords{#3}
}

\newcommand{\sectionFoot}[1]{
    % Keyword of the section
    \subsection[Table of tags]{Table of tags}
    \tableof{#1}
    \newpage
}

\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{%
    \def\nextitem{\def\nextitem{, }}
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\nextitem \hyperlink{##1}{##1} }
    \textbf{tags:} \docsvlist{ #1 }
}

\begin{document}

\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Ch 1}
\minitoc

    \sectionHead{Sec 1}{a}{a,b}

\lipsum[1]

    \sectionFoot{a}


    \sectionHead{Sec 2}{b}{a,b}

\lipsum[1]

    \sectionFoot{b}


    \sectionHead{Sec 3}{c}{c}

\lipsum[1]

    \sectionFoot{c}

\chapter{Ch 2}
\minitoc

    \sectionHead{Sec 4}{d}{a,d}

\lipsum[1]

    \sectionFoot{d}

    \sectionHead{Sec 5}{e}{e,f}

\lipsum[1]

    \sectionFoot{e}

    \sectionHead{Sec 6}{f}{f,b}

\lipsum[1]

    \sectionFoot{f}

\end{document}
```

Do you know how I should proceed to solve this ?

**Edit:** I tried the command

```
\setcounter{mtc}{*number of the chapter*}
```

without success.

Comment: `\tableofcontents` is defined by the common latex classes.  What are you actually trying to do?  What's your question?

Comment: @ThomasAuriel: Welcome to TeX.SE. You should **really** provide a compilable example

Comment: I made a minimal example. I manage to remove import and input function since they are not causing my issue.

Comment: It seems to be a problem of `tableof` with `\newpage` after `\tableof` command. I don't know why?

Comment: @touhami Add `Hello` right before `\end{document}`. Else there is an `\AtEndDocument` command issued by `tableof` which remains without effet. The main toc file is lacking a `\tof@finish` at its very end.

Comment: @jfbu `Hello ;-)`

Comment: @touhami just passing, but thanks... to preserve document with no extra page avoiding "evaporation" one can add this after `\begin{document}`: ``\makeatletter
\let\tof@finish\empty
\tof@toctoks=\expandafter{\the\tof@toctoks\tof@finish}
\makeatother``

Comment: @jfbu geat. The good point here is it seems there is no problem of compitibility  (`tableof--minitoc`) i will try to make more tests and give you informations.

Comment: @touhami there is afaict no issue of compatibility with `minitoc` as `tableof` does things in the most discrete manner. The annoying problem with `\end{document}` occurring after the last page was shipped out is a priori exceptional context. Its manifestation is somewhat surprising to the layman, though ;-) The fix adjusting manually `tof@toctoks` circumvents it for `\tableof` command, but would not for `\nexttocwithtags{}{}` followed by a `\tableofcontents` command or a `\localtableofcontents` from package etoc.

Comment: Thanks you for your responses!

@touhami, your solution solved my issue. I was not even close to find that. How can I mark it as a response?

Comment: your welcome :-) you can ask @jfbu to write an answer or you can add one your self.

Comment: I uploaded tableof 1.4b to CTAN to fix that issue. Sorry for delay... Will update my answer when this new version of tableof is available for download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### updated answer (october 2018)

Version 1.4b of [`tableof`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tableof) has been released to fix the root cause of this problem. (sorry for delay...)

---

#### original answer

(from comments)

There is a priori no incompatibility of `tableof` vs `minitoc`. The issue in your document comes from the fact that the last thing before `\end{document}` is a `\newpage` (as pointed out by @touhami). This means that `\end{document}` gets executed at a time the last page is already shipped out. This causes the loss of some instruction put by `tableof` in an `\AtEndDocument` command. As a result a macro is missing from the main `toc` file and you get the missing TOCs syndrom. The simplest is for the time being to avoid ending your document body with `\newpage` as the last thing. If this is unavoidable, then a not completely general workaround has been pointed out in comments.